# Film where girl falls in love in virtual reality. Ultimately meets the object of her desire only to find that she's elderly

Tags: story-identification, movie

A girl goes into virtual reality that is set in the past, she meets a girl there and falls for her, she keeps going back to try and find her, it's set in the 80's initially but then as she tries to find her she also searches through different eras.

In one scene she searches some weirdly erotic club in the desert maybe. It has a "lost boys" era type of feel about it. I think the opening scene is them driving a beach buggy in the dark. In the end she finds her in real life and she is old.

Probably 2010-2014 at a guess.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)  - Specifically, was this a soft-core pornographic film or something mainstream? How old was the girl protagonist. Who played her? Who played the love-interest?

Comment: They’re actually both older than they appear within the virtual reality world.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237857/virtual-reality-movie-where-they-upload-after-death-the-consciousness-into-the-c (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure about the "weirdly erotic club in the desert" part, but everything else sounds pretty much exactly like the Black Mirror episode [San Junipero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Junipero)

Maybe I'm just forgetting the desert club part.

Comment: The episode has the nightclub where they meet, which is in San Junipero itself.  It's not a desert, iirc it's a beach town though, so that may be where OP gets that from.

Comment: While searching for Kelly, the main character indeed attends another club, The Quagmire, that is much, much edgier.

Comment: There was a long, dark road leading to The Quagmire, which was set a way away from the rest of the beach resort type town. I don't remember if the area around it was desert or scrubland, but it was desert-like (a barren landscape with a Mad Max / frontier type vibe). The Lost Boys comparison fits. Everything in the question is in that episode, but the order of events and plot significance is jumbled up.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like San Junipero E4S3 Black Mirror, from 2016

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Junipero