# Virtual reality movie where they upload after death the consciousness into the cloud

Tags: story-identification, movie, virtual-worlds

The virtual world is an escape for an old lady before she dies and she goes to party in a young avatar of herself. Then she meets with the main male character and he chases her thought several virtual worlds like -70s, 50s punk and others. They finally hook up in the virtual and the man wants to find her and she gives him the address of the elderly home and he finds out that she is old and about to die. After that they upload her into the virtual world designed for dead people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [this related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/191918/58193) this sounds almost exactly like season 3 episode 4, "San Junipero", of *Black Mirror* (2016). The only difference being that it is two women and not a man and a woman.

> The next week, Yorkie visits another nightclub, the Quagmire, looking for Kelly. Wes advises her to "try a different time". Yorkie visits Tucker's in a few different decades until she finds Kelly in 2002, but Kelly rejects her. After Yorkie leaves, Kelly follows and confesses she is dying; Kelly had avoided Yorkie because she feared developing feelings for her. The two have sex again, and Yorkie reluctantly tells Kelly she lives in Santa Rosa, California, so they can meet.
>
> San Junipero is revealed to be a simulated reality where the deceased can live and the elderly can visit, all inhabiting their younger selves' bodies in a time of their choice. In the physical world, the elderly Kelly (Denise Burse) visits Yorkie (Annabel Davis). She learns from Yorkie's nurse, Greg (Raymond McAnally), that Yorkie was paralysed at age 21 after crashing her car when her parents reacted poorly to her coming out. Yorkie wishes to be euthanised to live in San Junipero permanently, but her family objects; she intends to marry Greg so that he can consent for her. Kelly offers to marry Yorkie instead, and after she enthusiastically accepts, Kelly authorises Yorkie's euthanasia.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, San Junipero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Junipero)</sub>

---

I found this by using the Google search `movie old lady virtual world` which turned up the linked question as the second result.

Comment: yes thats right sorry my memory is playing tricks :)

Comment: @TreantBG: No worries. It happens a lot. :-D I've had a number of cases myself.